# IS there a way to handle this error I'm receiving while using Node/Twit and Heroku?

Tags: node.js, heroku

I wrote a few Twitter bots with Node that I host on Heroku. I'm using Twit to interact with the Twitter API and lately, when I check the Heroku logs, I'm seeing this error. It doesn't happen around any tweet activity, just randomly happens. I can't seem to find much googling these error codes. The app crashes and then starts itself back up again in about three seconds, but I'm concerned about this constantly happening. Any ideas? pardon the syntax highlighting in js, not sure how to make it plain.

```
 node:events:504
2022-04-18T10:27:37.441762+00:00 app[worker.1]: throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
2022-04-18T10:27:37.441763+00:00 app[worker.1]: ^
2022-04-18T10:27:37.441763+00:00 app[worker.1]:
2022-04-18T10:27:37.441764+00:00 app[worker.1]: Error: aborted
2022-04-18T10:27:37.441766+00:00 app[worker.1]: at connResetException (node:internal/errors:691:14)
2022-04-18T10:27:37.441767+00:00 app[worker.1]: at TLSSocket.socketCloseListener (node:_http_client:402:19)
2022-04-18T10:27:37.441767+00:00 app[worker.1]: at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:538:35)
2022-04-18T10:27:37.441767+00:00 app[worker.1]: at node:net:687:12
2022-04-18T10:27:37.441768+00:00 app[worker.1]: at TCP.done (node:_tls_wrap:580:7)
2022-04-18T10:27:37.441769+00:00 app[worker.1]: Emitted 'error' event on StreamingAPIConnection instance at:
2022-04-18T10:27:37.441769+00:00 app[worker.1]: at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/twit/lib/streaming-api-connection.js:126:14)
2022-04-18T10:27:37.441770+00:00 app[worker.1]: at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:526:28)
2022-04-18T10:27:37.441770+00:00 app[worker.1]: at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
2022-04-18T10:27:37.441770+00:00 app[worker.1]: at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
2022-04-18T10:27:37.441771+00:00 app[worker.1]: at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
2022-04-18T10:27:37.441771+00:00 app[worker.1]: code: 'ECONNRESET'
```

Comment: Can you share also the code which is causing the issue? Otherwise we need to guess what you have done

Comment: Here's the repo for the project. The CI/CD is in there as well in the`.gitlab-ci.yml` file. 

https://gitlab.com/MetzinAround/DivasLive